# How to escape "/" in document name in Documentum DFC/DFS

Tags: escaping, documentum

How to escape "/" when you want to retrieve document like "/Templates/Blank Access 97 / 2000 Database" by object path in Documentum using DFS or DFC?

Comment: OS shouldn't matter here. The filesystem and escaping abstractions are both provided by Documentum.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you posted on http://developer.emc.com as well.  Not sure if you saw the response, but I believe it is the only way to do what you are asking for.  Alternatively, you could query for it using DQL and then use the Chronicle or Object ID to get it with DFS/DFC.

```
session.getObjectByQualification("dm_document where FOLDER('/Templates') and object_name='Blank Access 97 / 2000 Database'");
```

It looks like object names do not have this restriction.  For instance, when I query my repository with the following, I get loads of results:

```
select * from nlrb_document where title like '% / %'
```